# Which is correct?: "my childhood dream" or "my childhood’s dream"

Tags: apostrophe

As an English native speaker, I feel tempted to say

> "my childhood dream",

but from a grammatical perspective, would

> "my childhood's dream"

be more correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it won't.

The [Saxon genitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive) ('s) usually implies the preposition `of`.

`Childhood's dream` would imply dream **of** a childhood

What you want is an expression that means a dream ***from*** your childhood

`Childhood dream`, a spaced [compound noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Compound_nouns), is not only idiomatic but also correct.

<sub>Source: Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: It took a few seconds to get my head round it ;) Thanks